# How can I get proper `PropertyName` when I use Javers to diff objects

Tags: javers

```
class Person {
         @PropertyName("detail.change")
         Detail detail
}

class Detail {
         String name;
         String age;
}
```

I have a class named `Person`.
and it has a field named `detail` which is also an object
now i want to compare two `Person`
and no matter what the changes are, i want it returns me "detail.change" as the property name
for now if the name or age is different. javers returns me name or age
do you have any idea that i can do this?
really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can do it only if you map `Detail` to ValueType (https://javers.org/documentation/domain-configuration/#ValueType). ValueType is treated by Javers as atomic value. When `Detail` is mapped to ValueObject, Javers reports concrete properties of `Detail` as changed.